# jFileChooser save and cancel buttons are changed (Save will cancel and Cancel will Save) Java

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I'm making a simple Download manager in java.

When running the code in mac it works fine, but i went to test it in windows 7, and i got this problem:

If I click in save, it will leave the path to `C:\Users\Gui`

If I click to cancel, it will change it to `C:\Users\Gui\Documents`

[image: JFileChooser]

Code that i'm using:

```
JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser();
f.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
f.showSaveDialog(null);
tfPath.setText(f.getCurrentDirectory().toString());
```

Anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Read [the documentation for showSaveDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showSaveDialog-java.awt.Component-) and pay close attention to the return values.

Answer (score 0):

default directory of `JFileChooser` is user/documents for example
for me its

> C:\Users\Adeel Ahmad\Documents
>   for you it will be your C:\Users\your_login_account_name\Documents
>   use setcurrent directory to set the default directory when jfilechooser is opened

```
f.setCurrentDirectory("C:\somwhere");
```

Your code calls f.getCurrentDirectory() , which will give you the parent directory of whichever directory you're in when selecting a directory in JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY mode.
you might wanna use `f.getSelectedFile()` this is the reason you are getting `C:\Users\Gui\Documents` because when you save it,it gets its parent directory

and you can also know user selected save or cancel, `JFileChooser.showSaveDialog` returns an int which you can compare with constants of JFileChooser
you can take any action on the base of if user selected save or cancel by using
`JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION` or `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`(meaning save option)

```
JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser();
f.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
f.setCurrentDirectory(new File("D:\\"));
int result=f.showSaveDialog(null);
if(result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
tfPath.setText(f.getCurrentDirectory().toString());
```